# Conditionally apply a unique index

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql, unique-index

I am implementing functionality for a table that when an edit/change is made it will save a copy of the pre-edit row and mark it as is_deleted=TRUE, this is inorder to create a history of changes made to a row.

The email column in the table has a unique index which is preventing this functionality from being successful.

```
PostgreSQL said: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_email_unique"
Detail: Key (email)=(TEST) already exists.
```

Is there a way to apply the unique index only to rows that are marked is_deleted=FALSE, thus allowing for the changes to occur.

Answer (score 5):

Since version 7.2, you can use [partial indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html) in PostgreSql

Add a `where` clause to the `create index` statement to make it a partial index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_email_unique ON tests (email)
WHERE NOT is_deleted; -- assuming is_deleted is Boolean
```

Though PostgreSql supports [`Alter index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-alterindex.html), from what I understand from the documentation the alter is limited to either rename or setting the tablespace.

This means that you will need to [drop](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/sql-dropindex.html) and re-create the index in order to change it into a partial index:

```
DROP INDEX users_email_unique;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX users_email_unique ON tests (email)
WHERE NOT is_deleted; -- assuming is_deleted is Boolean
```